# Mixed content: This request has been blocked

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I've built an SPA with Laravel, Vue js, Vuex and Laravel Passport for authentication.
I have a vuex store file that contains the apiURL and serverPath that I use throughout my application via services, where I make my axios requests.
store.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import * as auth from './services/auth_service.js';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
   state: {
       apiURL: 'http://highrjobsadminlte.test/api',
       serverPath: 'http://highrjobsadminlte.test',
       profile: {},
   },
    mutations: {
        authenticate(state, payload) {
            state.isLoggedIn = auth.isLoggedIn();
            if (state.isLoggedIn) {
                state.profile = payload;
            } else {
                state.profile = {};
            }
        }
    },
    actions: {
        authenticate(context, payload) {
            context.commit('authenticate', payload)
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see in the apiURL and serverPath variables, I'm developing on my localhost using this domain: `http://highrjobsadminlte.test`

After deploying my application to GoDaddy, I changed these variables to my actual domain: `https://highrjobs.com`

Now I'm getting this error:

```
app.js:26402 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://highrjobs.com/candidate/search' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://highrjobsadminlte.test/api/candidate/search'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

When I click on the app.js file, I can see that it still has the store.js code with the local domain in the apiURL and serverPath variables, But they are changed in the files on the Server 1000%.

I thought it's a caching issue so I ran these commands:

```
php artisan route:cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

and it doesn't fix the issue. How can I fix this?

Comment: Stop adding the protocol to your URLS. Instead of `http://highrjobsadminlte.test/api` use `//highrjobsadminlte.test/api` instead of `http://highrjobsadminlte.test` use `//highrjobsadminlte.test`

Comment: Even though my application works perfectly on my Localhost machine?

Comment: I tried it, it didn't work. It still shows the same error message and I cleared my browser cache. It has to be a caching issue. Is there any other things I can try to clear all caches in my application?

Comment: Are you caching in php? Maybe using opcache?

Comment: I’m using Laravel. Are you familiar with the framework?

Answer (score 0):

> `Mixed content: This request has been blocked`

this error mostly get because

you are using `https://highrjobs.com` domain which is `https` protocol and u are using some url inside your application which is not `https`

```
  apiURL: 'http://highrjobsadminlte.test/api',
  serverPath: 'http://highrjobsadminlte.test',
```

like this u need to move in to `https`

in this error

> app.js:26402 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://highrjobs.com/candidate/search' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://highrjobsadminlte.test/api/candidate/search'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

you can clearly see server try to serve `https://highrjobs.com/candidate/search` this secure url  this unsecured  api `http://highrjobsadminlte.test/api/candidate/search`

so fix this u need to use `https` to your api url as well

hope i explained well

and your code should be

`apiURL: 'http://highrjobsadminlte.test/api'` to  `apiURL: 'https://highrjobs.com/api',`

Thank you

Comment: The issue was in my app.js file. It still had the .test URL's. How can I fix this?  I'm using Webpack and Laravel Mix. Why didn't it compile my latest changes? What command can I run?

Comment: npm run dev for latest webpack build

Answer (score -2):

Sorry, I forgot to run npm run production before deploying. So my app.js file still had the old URL's.